# Extract a substring from a string in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am looking to extract a substring from a string of variable length(input from the keyboard).

Here are my input:
1.A string.
2.An index/starting position for the substring.
3.length of the substring.
I am supposed to output the substring.
Here is a snippet where i try to get the substring.

```
cld ;df=0(forward)
lea si,buff
xor bx,bx
mov bx, offset pos ;starting index for substring
add si,bx
;add si,1
lea di,subst
mov cx, offset len ;length of the substring
rep movsb
mov bx,offset subst
xor si,si
mov si,offset len
mov byte ptr[bx+si+1],0 ;create a null terminated substring
```

in my result, the substring starts from the given position(pos), but then does not terminate when it reaches the given length.

Comment: don't move "offset len" to cx, move "len" to cx.

Comment: After the copy is done, es:di points to just after the last byte copied. In other words, it points to where the null needs to go. So, right after the rep movsb, you can null-terminate the substring with mov byte ptr es:[di],0

Comment: my substring starts from the right position but it does not end after len words, but goes instead till the end of the main string, even after making the suggested changes. maybe the rep movsb is not working well?

Comment: i put in a string :he is coming with the position at 3,and length of the substring at 4; i am getting :"is coming"

Comment: don't move "offset pos" to bx, move "pos" to bx

Answer (score 2):

```
xor bx,bx
mov bx, offset pos ;starting index for substring
```

When you `mov` a word value in a word register you don't need to empty this register first. Just drop the `xor bx,bx`

```
mov bx, offset pos
mov cx, offset len
```

When you use the *offset* tag you tell the assembler to use the address of your variable when in fact you need the value of the variable. So drop the *offset* tag and write `mov bx, pos` and `mov cx, len`

At the conclusion of `rep movsb` ES:DI points to where you want to place your null. Use this fact and save yourself the trouble of calculating this.

Here's what I propose you could write:

```
cld            ;df=0(forward)
mov bx, pos    ;starting index for substring
lea si, [buff + bx]  ; (1)
lea di, subst
mov cx, len    ;length of the substring
rep movsb
mov al, 0
stosb          ;create a null terminated substring
```

(1) This `lea si, [buff + bx]` replaces the 2 instructions `lea si, buff` and `add si, bx`

If you are going to output this substring with DOS function 09h you should not null terminate it but rather **$** terminate it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run your snippet I added only the necessary code to make it run, changes:

- Removed the "offset" to CX and BX (as suggested in comments).
- "pos" subtracted from CX after moving "len" to CX (to prevent going beyond length).
- Wayne Conrad suggestion.

Here is the code made with EMU8086 :

```
.model small

.stack 100h

.data

buff   db  'he is coming'                ;THE STRING.
len    dw  12                            ;STRING'S LENGTH.
pos    dw  3                             ;STARTING INDEX.
msj    db  13,10,'The substring is : $'
subst  db  12 dup('$')                   ;FILLED WITH '$' TO DISPLAY.

.code
start:

;INITIALIZE DATA AND EXTRA SEGMENTS.
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax
  mov  es, ax

;GET SUBSTRING.  
  call get_substring  

;DISPLAY SUBSTRING.  
  mov  dx, offset msj
  call printf
  mov  dx, offset subst
  call printf

;WAIT FOR ANY KEY.    
  mov  ah, 7
  int  21h

;FINISH PROGRAM.
  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h

;-----------------------------------------

get_substring proc
;EMEKA'S CODE.
  cld ;df=0(forward)
  lea si,buff
  xor bx,bx
  mov bx, pos              ;<=============== JOSE MANUEL!
  add si,bx
  ;add si,1
  lea di,subst
  mov cx, len              ;<=============== JOSE MANUEL!
  sub cx, pos              ;<=============== JOSE MANUEL!
  rep movsb
;  mov bx,offset subst
;  xor si,si
;  mov si,offset len
;  mov byte ptr[bx+si+1],0 ;create a null terminated substring    
  mov [ byte ptr es:di], 0 ;<=============== WAYNE CONRAD!

  ret
get_substring endp

;-----------------------------------------
;PARAMETER : DX POINTING TO '$' FINISHED STRING.
printf proc
  mov  ah, 9
  int  21h
  ret
printf endp    

;-----------------------------------------

end start
```

Comment: I like the comments :D

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a new real-mode's solution for 80x86+ microprocessors.
It uses JUMP instructions and it uses only a one string's instruction.

GetSubStr3's function keeps a sub-string of user-def-length characters
from the user-def-position of input-string.
All the strings are null terminated, so I process
the length of input-string.
The position of sub-string may be over the length
of input-string, so I normalize it ad I return it.
The length of sub-string may be large more then the length
of input-string, so I normalize it ad I return it.

This is the code, that I have successfully tested:

```
Procedure GetSubStr3; Assembler;

{ INPUT: DS:SI -> Address of input-string;
            DX -> Position of sub-string;
            BX -> Length of sub-string (except null);
         ES:DI -> Address of output's sub-string;
   TEMP: AL, CX
 OUTPUT: DS:SI -> Address of input-string;
            DX -> New position of sub-string;
            BX -> New length of sub-string (except null);
         ES:DI -> Address of output's sub-string}

Asm

     ClD                  {Clear flag of string's direction}

     Mov   CX,DX          {CX <- Counter of sub-string's position}
     JCXZ  @FindSubStrEnd {If count. of sub-string's p. == 0 ends cycle}

@FindSubStr:              {Search real position of sub-string}

     Cmp   [DS:SI],Byte(0){Compare a character from input-string with 0}
     JE    @FindSubStrEnd {If the comparison is successful, ends cycle}

     Inc   SI             {Increment offset of input-string}

     Loop  @FindSubStr    {Decr. count. of sub-str.'s position, go to next cycle}

@FindSubStrEnd:           {Adjust sub-string's position}

     Sub   DX,CX          {Sub-string's pos. -= amount of not read char.}

     Mov   CX,BX          {CX <- Counter of sub-string's length}
     JCXZ  @CopySubStrEnd {If count. of sub-string's l. == 0 ends cycle}

@CopySubStr:              {Copy sub-string of input-string into output}

     Mov   AL,[DS:SI]     {AL <- Character read from input-string}

     Or    AL,AL          {If character read == 0 ...}
     JE    @CopySubStrEnd {... go to add 0 to output's sub-string}

     Inc   SI             {Increment offset of input-string}

     StoSB                {Write ch. read into output's sub-str., incr. offset of output's sub-string}

     Loop  @CopySubStr    {Decr, count. of sub-str.'s length, go to next cycle}

@CopySubStrEnd:           {...}

     Sub   BX,CX          {Sub-string's len. -= amount of not read char.}

     Mov   [ES:DI],Byte(0){Add 0 to output's sub-string}

     Sub   SI,BX          {Restore ...}
     Sub   SI,DX          {... Offset of input-string}
     Sub   DI,BX          {Restore offset of output's sub-string}

End;
```

Here it is a old real-mode's solution for 80x86+ microprocessors.
It don't uses JUMP instructions and it uses strings' instructions;
it keeps a sub-string of user-def-length characters
from the user-def-position of input-string.
All the strings are null terminated, so I process
the length of input-string.
The position of sub-string may be over the length
of input-string, so I normalize it ad I return it.
The length of sub-string may be large more then the length
of input-string, so I normalize it ad I return it.

Thanks to Peter Cordes I've implemented some suggestions of him and I optimized the first code, that I have successfully tested:

```
Procedure GetSubStr2; Assembler;

{ INPUT: ES:DI -> Address of input-string;
            DX -> Position of sub-string;
            BX -> Length of sub-string (except null);
         DS:SI -> Address of output's sub-string;
   TEMP: AX, CX
 OUTPUT: DS:SI -> Address of input-string;
         ES:DI -> Address of output's sub-string;
            DX -> New position of sub-string;
            BX -> New length of sub-string (except null)}

Asm

    {Set CX's reg. with the length of
     the input-string (except null)
     without change the address
     of the input-string (ES:DI).
     ----------------------}

     ClD             {Clear string direction flag}

     XOr   AL,AL     {Set AL's reg. with null terminator}
     Mov   CX,0FFFFH {Set CX's reg. with maximum length of the string}

     RepNE ScaSB     {Search null and decrease CX's reg.}

     LAHF            {Load FZero flag into AH (Bit6)}
     Not   CX        {Set CX with the number of char. scanned}
     Sub   DI,CX     {Restore address of the input-string}
     ShL   AH,1      {...}
     ShL   AH,1      {... FCarry flag is set with (FZero flag after scan)}
     SbB   CX,0      {If it founds null decrease CX's reg.}

    {Set DX's reg. with the minimum
     value between the length
     of the input-string
     (except null) and the position
     of the sub-string to get.
     ----------------------.
      Input: DX, CX
     Output: DX= MIN(CX,DX).
       Temp: AX}

     Sub   DX,CX     {DX = DX - CX}
     SbB   AX,AX     {If DX < 0 set AX=0FFFFH else set AX=0}
     And   DX,AX     {If DX >= 0 set DX=0 else nothing}
     Add   DX,CX     {DX = DX + CX}

    {----------------------}

     Add   DI,DX     {ES:DI is the pointer to the sub-string to get}

     Sub   CX,DX     {DX= (input-string's length)-(sub-string's start)}

    {Set CX's reg. with the minimum
     value between (the length
     of the input-string)-(the
     new position of the
     sub-string) and the length
     of the sub-string.
     ----------------------
      Input: CX, BX
     Output: CX= MIN(CX,BX).
       Temp: AX}

     Sub   CX,BX     {CX = CX - BX}
     SbB   AX,AX     {If CX < 0 set AX=0FFFFH else set AX=0}
     And   CX,AX     {If CX >= 0 set CX=0 else nothing}
     Add   CX,BX     {CX = CX + BX}

    {----------------------}

     XChg  DI,SI     {Swap the address of the input-string with ...}
     Mov   AX,ES     {...}
     Mov   BX,DS     {...}
     Mov   ES,BX     {...}
     Mov   DS,AX     {... the address of the output's sub-string}

     Mov   BX,CX     {BX= New length of the output's sub-string}

     Rep   MovSB     {Copy the sub-string on the output}

     Mov   [ES:DI],Byte(0) {Set null t. to the end of the output's sub-string}

     Sub   DI,BX     {Restore address of output's sub-string}
     Sub   SI,BX     {Restore address of input-string}

End;
```

First code written by me:

```
Procedure GetSubStr; Assembler;

{ INPUT: ES:DI -> Address of input-string;
            DX -> Position of sub-string;
            BX -> Length of sub-string (except null);
         DS:SI -> Address of output's sub-string;
   TEMP: AX, CX
 OUTPUT: DS:SI -> Address of input-string;
         ES:DI -> Address of output's sub-string;
            DX -> New position of sub-string;
            BX -> New length of sub-string (except null)}

Asm

    {Set CX's reg. with the length of
     the input-string (except null)
     without change the address
     of the input-string (ES:DI).
     ----------------------}

     ClD             {Clear string direction flag}

     XOr   AL,AL     {Set AL's reg. with null terminator}
     Mov   CX,0FFFFH {Set CX's reg. with maximum length of the string}

     RepNE ScaSB     {Search null and decrease CX's reg.}

     LAHF            {Load FZero flag into AH (Bit6)}
     Not   CX        {Set CX with the number of char. scanned}
     Sub   DI,CX     {Restore address of the input-string}
     ShL   AH,1      {...}
     ShL   AH,1      {... FCarry flag is set with (FZero flag after scan)}
     SbB   CX,0      {If it founds null decrease CX's reg.}

    {Set DX's reg. with the minimum
     value between the length
     of the input-string
     (except null) and the position
     of the sub-string to get.
     ----------------------.
      Input: DX, CX
     Output: DX= MIN(CX,DX).
       Temp: AX}

     Sub   DX,CX     {DX = DX - CX}
     SbB   AX,AX     {If DX < 0 set AX=0FFFFH else set AX=0}
     And   DX,AX     {If DX >= 0 set DX=0 else nothing}
     Add   DX,CX     {DX = DX + CX}

    {----------------------}

     Add   DI,DX     {ES:DI is the pointer to the sub-string to get}

     Sub   CX,DX     {DX= (input-string's length)-(sub-string's start)}

    {Set CX's reg. with the minimum
     value between (the length
     of the input-string)-(the
     new position of the
     sub-string) and the length
     of the sub-string.
     ----------------------
      Input: CX, BX
     Output: CX= MIN(CX,BX).
       Temp: AX}

     Sub   CX,BX     {CX = CX - BX}
     SbB   AX,AX     {If CX < 0 set AX=0FFFFH else set AX=0}
     And   CX,AX     {If CX >= 0 set CX=0 else nothing}
     Add   CX,BX     {CX = CX + BX}

    {----------------------}

     XChg  DI,SI     {Swap the address of the input-string with ...}
     Mov   AX,ES     {...}
     Mov   BX,DS     {...}
     XChg  AX,BX     {...}
     Mov   ES,AX     {...}
     Mov   DS,BX     {... the address of the output's sub-string}

     Mov   BX,CX     {BX= New length of the output's sub-string}

     Rep   MovSB     {Copy the sub-string on the output}

     XOr   AL,AL     {Set AL's reg. with null terminator}
     StoSB           {Set null t. to the end of the output's sub-string}

     Sub   DI,BX     {Restore address of output's sub-string}
     Sub   SI,BX     {Restore address of input-string}

End;
```

Hi!

Comment: Why do you need `XChg  AX,BX` instead of just changing the operands to `Mov   ES,AX` and `Mov   DS,BX`?  Also, xor/stosb isn't better than `mov byte [di], 0`

Comment: I think you could simplify this a lot if you put the substring position + length into CX before the first `repne scasb`, so you get the copy-limit position whether it's the end of the input string or the end of the requested substring.  It might also be better to just copy a byte at a time instead of finding the string length first.  Then you could use segment overrides and wouldn't have to confusingly swap ES and DS.  (Or you could require both buffers in DS, and use segment overrides on every rep-string instruction to use DS:SI and DS:DI, I think.)

Comment: you are right about the use of mov [ES: DI], Byte (0) instead of StoSB and also with regard to swap of ES with DS. But if I add CX with the position of the string to be extracted, before Rep ScaSB, I do not realize that this position might be out of the input string.

Comment: `repne scasb` stops on count=0 or on finding the end of the string.  If you give it a starting CX=(length+position), it will always stop at the end of the block you want to copy from.  You're right that just `position` wouldn't check if `pos+length` went outside the input string, though.